# Dataservice Query Conditional Expand

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, odata

I was wondering when querying a ODATA service with LINQ if I can expand only if a value exists. I have a parent object that possess a property that is another object that possess a object collection.

Example:

```
class Object1
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public Object2 {get; set;}

}

class Object2
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public List<Object3> childCollection {get; set;}
}
```

My query is as so:

```
var data = datacontext.Object1.Expand("Object2/ChildCollection")
```

This fails because some of the OBJECT1 do not have a OBJECT2. Is there a way around this like conditionally expanding?

Comment: When `Object1` does not have an `Object2` object, `Object2` is `null` but the query doesn't fail. I think it's only your post processing that fails. Maybe you can elaborate on that a bit.

Comment: Everytime I try the query I get a Payload error from the server. When I dig deeper it complains about a Null. If i remove the ChildCollection from the expand it runs fine. So obviously it's the child Collection of the child Object2 that is freaking ODATA or the server out. I thought ODATA could handle nulls.

Comment: Are you using web API or WCF data services?